# How to make automator app use a specific folder as input

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I have a number of processes that I need a Mac Mini to run with no input.

One of these tasks is to take ingested video files, rename them and transfer them to another location.

The app I am using to ingest the files is called one way sync and it is capable of running a script upon completion. Using this, I can trigger an automator app to run. However I do not know a way to specify the input for this app as the contents of X folder.

I need the app to run on the contents of folder X every time.

Can anybody tell me what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's documentation on files is a bit of a laundry list - but read a little so you can decide if you want to use POSIX names or native names. POSIX uses / and native uses : to denote folder breaks. The following two lines are both the Downloads folder for a user with a short name of **me**:

```
"/Users/me/Downloads"
"Macintosh HD:Users:me:Downloads"
```

[Mac Automation - Files and Folders - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH34-SW1)

On the left sidebar are links to sections dealing with [Processing dropped files and folders](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ProcessDroppedFilesandFolders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH53-SW1) as well as the concept of [watching folders](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WatchFolders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH39-SW1).

I would try my hand at writing a script that uses the built in watch folders triggers so you don't have to deal with passing file names or starting and stopping the script. If that doesn't work, you could always invest in a tool like [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com) that does what you want as well, but it's good to try and learn automation since it's so powerful long term.